# How do I enable the GameOver Menu with conditions of the position of the animator?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an animator in Unity created in Blender, with 3 scenes, Idle, Walking, and Raising Hand. How can I implement the game over menu to appear when for example the position of the animator on axis Z is between -6 and -4 and the animator is raising a hand? the purpose is to raise a hand just when arriving at a table. And how can I find the coordination of the animator next to the table since if I move in the scene the animator, it gives me some coordinates and when I run it and move the animator through keys, it has different coordinates?

```
if (!(transform.position.z >= -6f && transform.position.z <= -4f) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
{
    EnableGameOverMenu();
}
else if (transform.position.z >= -4f && transform.position.z <= -1f && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
{
    EnableGameOverMenu();
}
```

I tried like this and the menu appears every time I hit the key to raise hand. In the first condition when I delete the negation, because I want it to appear when it is in that interval and raise hand, the menu does not appear at all.

Answer (score 3):

You should go through [Animation Events](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-AnimationWindowEvent.html)!

On your component you could have some simple flags that are assigned by the events like e.g.

```
private bool loseIfRaiseHand;
private bool loseIfNotRaiseHand;

public void SetLoseIfRaiseHand(bool value)
{
    loseIfRaiseHand = value;
}

public void SetLoseIfNotRaiseHand(bool value)
{
    loseIfNotRaiseHand = value;
}

private void Update()
{
    if(loseIfRaiseHand && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)
       || loseIfNotRaiseHand && !Input.GetKey(Keycode.Space))
    {
        EnableGameOverMenu();
    }
}
```

and then within your Animation you would setup the events like e.g.

```
time 0 ................... reaching table ......... after reached table
     |                     |                        |
     |                     |                        SetLoseIfNotRaiseHand(true)
SetLoseIfRaiseHand(true)  SetLoseIfRaiseHand(false)
```

the time between `reaching table` and `after reached table` is the reaction time your users have to get their hand up .. so it shouldn't be too small ;)